# Vue js spread syntax with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuex

When using [vuex mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html), the documentation says you can use 
spread syntax as below, which I have working as intended.

I'm just curious as to what this is actually doing, so I have a better understanding of using spread syntax.

Would this...

```
computed: {
  ...mapState([
    'message',
    'storeArray'
  ])
}
```

Be effectively doing this... ?

```
computed: {
  message(){
    return this.$store.state.message
  }
  storeArray(){
    return this.$store.state.storeArray
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

What `mapState` does is returning an object with the functions, so effectively it is returning

```
{ 
  message(){
    return this.$store.state.message
  }
  storeArray(){
    return this.$store.state.storeArray
  }
}
```

or actually

```
{ 
  message: function(){
    return this.$store.state.message
  }
  storeArray: function(){
    return this.$store.state.storeArray
  }
}
```

which is the same thing.

What the spread operator does is extracting the objects keys and puts them into the parent object, replacing any already existing keys with the same name.

So it's basically the same as doing:

```
computed: {
  message: mapState(['message','storeArray'])['message'],
  storeArray: mapState(['message','storeArray'])['storeArray']
}
```

You can think of the spread operator as an easier way of using `Object.assign`.

```
computed: {...mapState(...), ...myOtherComputedObject)
computed: Object.assign({}, mapState(...), myOtherComputedObject)
```

Answer (score 3):

Like they say in [official doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#object-spread-operator) :

> Note that mapState returns an object. How do we use it in combination with other local computed properties? Normally, we'd have to use a utility to merge multiple objects into one so that we can pass the final object to computed. However with the [object spread operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) (which is a stage-4 ECMAScript proposal), we can greatly simplify the syntax:
>
> ```
>  computed: {
>     localComputed () { /* ... */ },
>     // mix this into the outer object with the object spread operator
>     ...mapState({
>       // ...
>     })
>   }
> ```

this syntax is used to simplify and provide a **clean** code and also it is necessary when you're using locale `computed` properties

Comment: This helped. It wasn't clear from the docs that the 3 dots do represent the actual operator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [This discussion](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator) is relevant.

> While effective, using Object.assign() can quickly make simple
>   reducers difficult to read given its rather verbose syntax.
>
> An alternative approach is to use the object spread syntax recently
>   added to the JavaScript specification. It lets you use the spread
>   (...) operator to copy enumerable properties from one object to
>   another in a more succinct way.